# Create vector char array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, free, memcpy

I am trying to create an array of c string in C, which simulates a behavior similar to that of vector array in c++. The array doubles its capacity whenever the (currentSize + 1) is equal to (MAX_SIZE). This is how I am doing it:

```
void addLog(char ** dynamicArray, int* size, int *maxSize, int command){
    if (*size < *maxSize){
        dynamicArray[*size] = "User selects option 1 from main menu.";
        (*size)++;
    }
    else{
        //resizing the array here
        int originalSize = *maxSize;
        *maxSize = *maxSize * 2;
        //copy elements of dynamic array in temporary array
        char **tempArray = (char**)malloc(originalSize * sizeof(char*));
        for (int i = 0; i < originalSize; ++i){
            memcpy(&tempArray[i], &dynamicArray[i], sizeof(dynamicArray[i]));
        }

        //create new array of max * 2 size
        dynamicArray = (char**)malloc(*maxSize * sizeof(char*));
        //copy temp to dynamic
        for (int i = 0; i < originalSize; ++i){
            memcpy(&dynamicArray[i], &tempArray[i], strlen(tempArray[i]));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < originalSize; i++) {
            free(tempArray[i]); <---- this throws an exception on heap
        }
        free(tempArray);
        //insert new element now
        dynamicArray[*size] = "User selects option 1 from main menu.";
        (*size)++;
    }
}
```

I believe this is a trivial problem for a deep copy scenario. How to resize dynamic array to 2 * capacity and then free the temporary existing elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a reusable implementation yourself by extending a struct.

This is a bit long, but it walks you through the entire process and should have everything you need to know:

http://eddmann.com/posts/implementing-a-dynamic-vector-array-in-c/

> The structure will take advantage of a fixed-size array, with a counter invariant that keeps track of how many elements are currently present. If the underlying array becomes exhausted, the addition operation will re-allocate the contents to a larger size, by way of a copy."

Comment: This needs expansion and at least a summation of the salient points of the link  to be a good answer. For example, what if eddmann.com is a porn site a week from now? Kind of changes the usefulness of the answer.